# Prometheus topk function returning all results

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to graph out the top 5 users by their login count in the last 24 hours. But when I use the below `topk` function, I am getting all the user login within that time range.

Query:
`topk(10, sum(my_app_login) by (User_Name) != 0)`

[image]

How do I limit it to only top 10?

Comment: It seems that the value of 1 falls into the top 10. I think this should resolve by itself when you have more data. Right now you can change the top 10 to top 5 and check whether you've got the result you want.

Comment: There are more than 20 unique values which are greater than 1. Also I just tried to print top 3.. But it didn't help either.

Comment: Weird, the query seems OK. Try running the query in Prometheus console, does it produce the expected result?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, storing something that has an unlimited range of possible values in a label is usually a bad idea. It will drastically affect Prometheus database size and performance, be careful with this metric.

Comment: Unfortunately, the prometheus console is not exposed for us, so will not be able to use it directly. However, I have notified our internal prometheus admin, awaiting their response.

Comment: When you say its not a good idea, then how do you propose I display this type of data in graphana? How best to expose these type of metrics?

Comment: If you cannot use Prometheus directly, there is the `explore` button on the left sidebar in Grafana. You can try there. As for this type of data, there are some workarounds, but it's a question on it own and it probably has been answered already. In short, it's better to use logs or collect that data with caution and on infrequent (5m) intervals.

Comment: realy good suggestion by @anemyte 
labels should always have low cardinality. Username is not such thing. You should ask, why you want a metric based on username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to enable [instant query](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#instant-queries-in-dashboards) in Grafana. In this case Grafana will return only the last data point on the selected time range per each resulting time series instead of returning many data points per time series on the selected time range.

Other considerations:

- if `my_app_login` is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), then the following query should returns top users with the most login actions during the last 24 hours:

```
topk(10, sum(increase(my_app_login[24h])) by (User_Name))
```

Note that Prometheus may return fractional results from this query even if `my_app_login` contains only integer values. This is because of data model quirks for `increase()` function in Prometheus - see [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for details. If you need exact integer results, then take a look at [MetricsQL from VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).

- if `my_app_login` is a [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge), which contains the number of app logins since the previous sample, then the following query should work:

```
topk(10, sum(sum_over_time(my_app_login[24h])) by (User_Name))
```

See [sum_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) for more details.

Note that [topk(N, ...)](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk) function may return more than `N` time series when this function is used for building a graph over time (aka [range query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries)). This is because it returns top `N` time series independently per each timestamp on the graph. If you need no more than top `N` time series on the graph, then take a look at [topk_max](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_max), [topk_last](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_last) and other `topk_*` functions from MetricsQL.

Comment: Thanks Valyala. It was indeed a `guage` type metric and the second suggestion of useing the `sum_over_time` helped